# Google Drive API with Python not allowing file download despite correct scopes being added

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I have followed the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) given by Google for using Python and I have used the appropriate scope as given by Google for downloading files from the Drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly but I keep getting the error of:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1RWpLGCWldcJyVqa0tIVlScg60ExEtcNIvJ7R9M8DuhM?alt=media
>   returned "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export
>   with Google Docs files."

When I try to run the code to download the files.

I can read what files are on the drive, but I cannot seem to download a particular spreadsheet from the drive despite my best efforts. Here is my code (redacted file paths and some commenting) below for establishing the connection through the API:

```html
def gsuite_connect():

    file_path = 'OMITTED/Loading'

    # Get what permissions the user (using the API) will need. This as been set to high level
    # access by default
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
    
    # Access the tokens for G Suite to access the Drive. Ensure that if this file previous exists,
    # that it is in the current working directory
    store = file.Storage(os.path.join(file_path, 'storage.json'))
    
    # Access the credentials for the Drive API
    creds = store.get()
    
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        print("\nUsing credentials found in client_id(secret).json")
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(os.path.join(file_path, 'client_id.json'), scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    
    http = creds.authorize(Http())
    drive = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    sheets = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http)
    
    return drive, sheets
```

Here is the function (redacted file paths and some commenting) I use for downloading the files based on what [Google provides](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads):

```html
    def get_datalog(self):

        dir_path = 'OMITTED/Downloads'
        fname = "'FILENAME'"
        files = self.drive.files().list(q="name = {}".format(fname),
                                        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = files.get('files', [])

        # Error checking and subsequent downloading if file successfully found
        if not items:
            exit()
        else:

            # Change into the desired directory for storing the file and download file based on the
            # retrieved ID
            os.chdir(dir_path)
            file_id = items[0]['id']

            # Request download service
            request = self.drive.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

            fh = io.FileIO(fname, mode='w')
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

            # Return the file path
            return os.path.join(dir_path, fname)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! I do not want to show sensitive files such as the client_id.json or any other credentials but do let me know if you need further information!

Comment: The code as it is does not present anything wrong, and should work properly, this leads me to thing on what type of file are you trying to download. I believe it has something to do with the file format and size, so please, specify this details in order to debug it properly.

Comment: Use: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get to see the mime type of the file.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply Santhosh. It is a Google Sheet . I am not able to access other files as well nor am I able to read data from the sheet. I get the same error which leads me to think something else may be at play.

Comment: I was getting the same error. In my situation the reason was that i had the wrong file id.I was opening the file in google drive and was taking the id from the url,in the browser address bar. This was wrong. So what i did was retrieve all the files through code, using the API, and i noticed that the file ids where different. So when i used the file id returned from the API,i was able to use this id to retrieve the file. I doubt this will help anyone, but here's my two cents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You want to download Google Docs (in your situation, it's Spreadsheet.) using google-api-python-client with python.
- You want to know the reason of the error of `Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.`
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- When the Google Docs files are downloaded by `get_media` method, such error occurs.

  - In the case of `get_media` method, the files except for Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, Slides and so on) can be downloaded.
- When you want to download Google Docs files, please use `export_media` method.

  - In this case, the raw Google Docs cannot be downloaded because of the specification of Google side. So please convert it to other format. For example, in the case of Spreadsheet, it's Excel format, CSV format and so on.

#### Modified script:

In order to avoid the issue, how about the following modification?

From:

```
request = self.drive.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
```

To:

```
request = self.drive.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```

- In this case, the Google Spreadsheet is downloaded as Excel file. If you want to download it as CSV, please modify the mimeType to `text/csv`.

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that the Google Docs file you want to download is yours or the publicly shared.

#### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

About the method for changing the scopes for the access token, please rename or delete the file of `storage.json` in your script, and run the script again. By this, you can reauthorize for the new scopes and new file including the tokens is created. And you can use the access token with the new scopes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer @Tanaike. Unfortunately, I am still getting an error of: `"Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">` despite me using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`. However! I have just noticed that the `storage.json` file which contains my `scope` and `scopes` fields keeps changing the scope back to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` which was the scope I first used when I ran the generic `quickstart.py` from Google. Is there perhaps a hidden file somewhere I need to delete?

Comment: @user2013373 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your case, please rename or delete the file of `storage.json` and run the script again. By this, you can reauthorize for the new scopes and new file is created. And you can use the access token with the new scopes. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, absolutely no need to apologize! You have been so helpful and I was able to solve this by doing exactly that and I just came on here to tell you but see that you also found the solution! Once again, thank you so much for taking the time to be so helpful :)

Comment: @user2013373 Thank you for replying. If above method resolved your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @user2013373 Can I ask you about your current issue? If my answer is not complete for resolving your issue, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike your comment led me to the right answer but I unfortunately am not allowed to accept that as the answered as far as I know. Maybe add an update to your original answer and I can then accept that?

Comment: @user2013373 Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this and it's works with the following library:

```
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2
```

This is the snippet I'm using:

```
from apiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def download_google_document_from_drive(self, file_id):
    try:

        request = self.service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
        return fh
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error downloading file from Google Drive: %s' % e)
```

You can write the file stream to a file:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=fh.getvalue())
```

As for the scopes I'm using the following snippets:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.service = build('drive', 'v3',
                    credentials=self._service_account_credentials())

def _service_account_credentials(self.):
   service_account_key_path = os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')

   credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
     service_account_key_path)
   scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
     ['https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'])
   signer_email = scoped_credentials.service_account_email
   signer = scoped_credentials.signer

   credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
     signer,
     signer_email,
     token_uri='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
   )
   return credentials
```